# KornShell (ksh): Use read input or default value

Tags: ksh

Using KornShell, I want to ask the user for an input, and use a default value if no input is given. Of course if he entered something it should use the entered value.

My script so far:

```
echo "Choose a script to start"
read input?"Start Script: "
```

The default value should be next to the question, like this:

> Start script: [script1]

KornShell is something new for me, but I am interested in it and would like to get to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention what the default is, or how you want to manage it (eg, as a variable, as a static string).

There are many ways to handle the input; one simple example ...

The script (wanna_play):

```
$ cat wanna_play
#!/bin/ksh

dflt='spider'

echo "Choose a script to start"
read input?"Start Script: [${dflt}] "

[[ "${input}" = '' ]] && input=${dflt}

echo "Entered: ${input}"
```

And a couple sample runs:

```
$ wanna_play
Choose a script to start
Start Script: [spider]
Entered: spider

$ wanna_play
Choose a script to start
Start Script: [spider] freecell
Entered: freecell
```

---

I suggest you do some web searches for learning ksh ... lots of useful info on the internet; one good starter book: [O'Reilly: Learning the Korn Shell](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn)